# Advice on enterprise architecture

Tags: networking, web-server, network-design

I'm a developer for a large company (that shall remain nameless) and we are currently brainstorming ideas for re-engineering our network architecture. We receive about 7 million hits per day and we're growing. Our system we have now is about comprised of several Poweredge 2650s and we keep some in live status, and we can switch over to backups should something occur. We basically have a system that has sort of grown up and expanded as we've needed, but now we need to look at re-engineering the whole thing.

Question I have is regarding profiles of other large companies and what they are doing. What kind of architecture do they have in place to handle their users?

Are there any books or case studies that anyone knows regarding this topic? How would I go about finding out how Amazon, Yahoo! and other very large companies serve the public in this way.

Many thanks!
Wilkie

Answer (score 1):

This article is a bit dated but should be at least an interesting read.  Its about how Microsoft converted over Hotmail from Unix to Windows Server and some of the challenges and design that they choose to use.  Its based around win2k so some parts aren't valid anymore but its got a good discussion about strengths and weaknesses of the two systems when dealing with a large system

http://www.securityoffice.net/mssecrets/hotmail.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found it pretty interesting to read the [facebook engineering notes](http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=9445547199).  Here is another nice [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/iamcal/scalable-web-architectures-common-patterns-and-approaches-web-20-expo-nyc-presentation) on scalability.